# ASP.NET CORE 2.0 localhost refused to connect on mac but works on windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, asp.net-core

I've been working on a web app using ASP.NET Core 2.0. The solution was originally created on a windows machine and it works fine. When I try to launch it on my Mac, it launches and when it opens the website on Chrome, it says localhost refused to connect. I have run out of ideas and haven't found anything useful online.

I have a feeling it is related to SSL. In VS, it says `Now listening on: http://localhost:51684`, but the browser opens the URL `https://localhost/`. No port or anything. When I paste `http://localhost:51684`, it just forwards to `https://localhost/` again.

My launchsettings.json file contains the following

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44314/",
      "sslPort": 44314
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "TestApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51684/"
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to access the URL listed in iisSettings `https://localhost:44314/` I get the same localhost refused to connect message.

This is what is in my Startup.cs file

```
public class Startup
{

    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(
            options => options.UseMySql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<TestDbContext>();
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        });
        services.AddScoped<IUserDAL, UserDAL>();
        services.AddScoped<ITestDataDAL, TestDataDAL>();
        services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent());
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);
    }

    private void ConfigureRoutes(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
    {
        routeBuilder.MapRoute("Default",
            "{controller=User}/{action=Register}/{id?}");
    }
}
```

I'm not very experienced with ASP.NET Core and I can't think of any solutions. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: You have https redirect enabled in Configure but no https endpoint configured. The redirect is also perma cached so you may need to clear your browser cache after changing it.

Comment: I thought it would use a default endpoint in the launchsettings. That doesn't explain why it would work on Windows and not Mac though.

Comment: Can you please try running on macOS by commenting out the following line `  options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());`?

Comment: It might be working fine on Windows because you probably allowed VS to generate a self-signed cert and trust it. On macOS that step was never executed.

Comment: There's two sets of config in launch settings, IIS Express and other.  The IIS Express settings don't apply on Mac. There's a lot of improvements coming here for 2.1 for this work seamlessly.

Comment: Abhay Saraf, removing the lines did let me run it properly since it wasn't requiring https. It also completely makes sense about the self signed cert. Completely forgot about doing that step when I worked on that part in Windows. Tratcher, I'll take a look at the other launch settings to see if I can get it to work. For now, I'll leave the lines commented out. Thanks for helping me look into this guys.